# Evento onkey - Necesita un carácter extra

Tags: javascript, onkey

Tengo un campo en un formulario, el campo se llama **DNI**, donde quiero ingresar 8 números y **una letra**. La letra automáticamente cual pongamos la convierte en mayúsculas mediante el método **toUpperCase().**

El problema que tengo que cualquier evento de **onkey (onkeypress, onkeyup, onkeydown)** no me funciona directamente, necesita un carácter más para "convertir" la anterior letra. No funciona directamente sobre la letra introducida.

**Archivo .js**

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    //Convertimos la letra del DNI en mayúscula en tiempo real con el evento onkeyup "toUpperCase()".
    $('#dni').on('keydown', letra_DNI);
});

//Función que convierte la tecla del DNI en mayúscula.
function letra_DNI(e){
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

**Archivo .html:**

```
<input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" maxlength="9" tabindex="4" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloLetrasNumeros(event);">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución puede ser:

en el evento `keypress` en el que todavía no se ha incluido el carácter en el input compruebas si el carácter pulsado es válido

en el evento `keyup` en el que ya se ha incluido el carácter en el input cambias cualquier carácter en minúsculas por el correspondiente en mayúsculas

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo.

En el evento `keypress` se comprueba que el carácter sea un número y que aún no se hayan introducido 8, o que sea una letra y ya se hayan introducido los 8 dígitos. Si no, rechaza la entrada.

En el evento `keyup` reemplaza cualquier letra minúscula introducida por la correspondiente en mayúsculas.

```js
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    //Convertimos la letra del DNI en mayúscula en tiempo real con el evento onkeyup "toUpperCase()".
    $('#dni').on('keypress', soloLetrasNumeros);
    $('#dni').on('keyup', letra_DNI);
});

//Función que convierte la tecla del DNI en mayúscula.
function letra_DNI(e){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/([a-z])/g, x => x.toUpperCase()));
}
function soloLetrasNumeros(e){
  // Si es número y no se han introducido 8 ok
  if (/^\d$/.test(e.key) &&
        $(this).val().length < 8) return true;
  // Si es letra y el valor de la entrada son 8 números
  if (/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(e.key) && 
        /\d{8}/.test($(this).val())) return true;
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" maxlength="9" tabindex="4" class="input-2">
```

Comment: Y para completar tu respuesta @Asier ¿si deseo que los 8 primeros solo permita numeros? Osea que si es letra bloquee el caracter...

Comment: No tienes más que modificar la expresión regular que comprueba que el valor de la entrada es válido para introducir una letra. Edito mi respuesta para contemplarlo.

Comment: Listo. También comprueba que únicamente se puedan introducir 8 dígitos.

Answer (score 3):

Si utilizas el [evento de teclado keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) no tendrás problemas.

```js
document.querySelector('#dni').onkeyup = function(e) {
  this.value = String(this.value || '').toUpperCase();
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dni" placeholder="DNI">
```